# how to do double tunneling to send big data?

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have 4 computer A, B, C, and D. Computer A and B in one city and Computer C and D in another city. Computer A and D are two cluster machine.
Computer B and C is connected through VPN. I have a huge data ~TB in computer A and want to send in computer D. What is the best way to send?
I put following information in computer B so that I can tunnel through C and directly send the data from computer B to D. But how to do send from computer A to D?

```
Host C
Hostname C.*** User <USERNAME>
IdentityFile  ̃/.ssh/id_rsa

Host D
Hostname D.*** User <USERNAME>
ProxyCommand ssh C nc %h %p
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProxyJump`, it is the same as `ssh -J` i.e. connecting via jump hosts.

```
scp -oProxyJump=userB@B,userC@C file userD@D:/path/to/target
```

Skip defining users, if no need be:

```
scp -oProxyJump=B,C file D:/path/to/target
```

> man 5 ssh_config
>
> ProxyJump
>
> Specifies one or more jump proxies as either [user@]host[:port] or an ssh URI. Multiple proxies may be separated by comma characters and will be visited sequentially.  Setting this option will cause ssh(1) to connect to the target host by first making a ssh(1) connection to the specified ProxyJump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate target from there.

---

Considering the size of your files, you might be interested in a failsafe in case of interrupted connections. `rsync` could resume interrupted transfers and make use of `ssh`'s jump host option:

```
rsync -P -e"ssh -oProxyJump=userB@B,userC@C" file userD@D:/path/to/target/
```

Comment: Thanks @FelixJN I have two user in dfferent city. So I did this. `user1@A:~$ scp -oProxyJump=user1@B,user2@C file.dat  user2@D:` Then I entered the password of B and got error. Password: channel 0: open failed: connect failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known stdio forwarding failed ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host lost connection

Comment: How to give password of C here.

Comment: Clearly the problem is not with the password of C, it rather seems B cannot connect to C in the first place. In case of multiple users, you should be prompted for the passwords step by step. Try manually going from A to D via B and C, i.e. ssh to B, from there to C, from there to D. Any problems doing so?

Comment: Thanks it is working. There was some problem in password. Great Many thank.